# How to split string and rename files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to bulk rename the files in my folder, and all of them have the format of `FilenameYeara\b.pdf`, for example, `TestData2001a.pdf`, `File2015b.pdf`. I want to rename all of them to something like `[Yeara\b]Filename`, such as `[2001a]TestData`. The problem is that I don't know how can I split my filename into two parts (actually three if we count the extension, .pdf part), such that I put that second part as the first part of the file name.

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item {$_.name -replace ‘current’, ’old’ }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It would depend on the conditions on which you split/move the strings around.  String manipulation isn't hard.. if you explicitly know you **always** expect some alphabetical characters, and some numbers, etc.  It's when it's not set-in-stone that you run into trouble.

That being said - do you **always** expect alphabetical characters, a 4-digit year, and then a single alphabet in the original filenames?

Comment: @gravity Yes, always. But I'm really not good with regular expressions and stuff.

Comment: Ok, and one more question - you know that `[` and slashes (/ \\) aren't generally allowable characters?  They're scattered around in most of your filename examples, and I wanted to ensure that you didn't expect that to be possible.

Comment: @gravity I used \ to mean that I can get after year either letter a or letter b, so as a choice I meant. Whereas `[` and `]`, I want to use them as part of the final filename, and I don't see that they make problem. Windows accepts brackets as part of the filename.

Comment: Sure, you can use brackets/braces... it's just not something commonly encountered... slashes, are a whole other issue.  :)

Comment: @gravity Yep, I know the pain, but I like brackets xD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the regex match "*anything, four digits, one character, .pdf*" and replaces it with those items in the new ordering.

```
PS D:\t> gci | ren -newname { $_ -replace '(.*)(\d{4})(.)\.pdf', '[$2$3]$1.pdf' }

    Directory: D:\t

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        13/05/2016     02:54          0 File2015b.pdf
-a---        13/05/2016     02:53          0 TestData2001a.pdf
```

becomes

```
    Directory: D:\t

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        13/05/2016     02:53          0 [2001a]TestData.pdf
-a---        13/05/2016     02:54          0 [2015b]File.pdf
```

(Maybe try it with `-Whatif` before running for real)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

```
$Matches.Clear()
Get-Item | % {
   $_.BaseName -match "(\D+)([0-9]{4}[ab])"
   Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($Matches[2])$($Matches[1])$($_.Extension)"
}
```